# How to get file url from SPFile object?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I want to know that how can i get the file's url in below format using C#:

Library Name: "Shared Documents"
Root Folder: "Folder 1"

Sub Folder(in Folder 1): "In Folder 1"

Sub Folder(inside In Folder 1): "Inside in Folder 1"

http://myservername:150/Shared Documents/Folder 1/In Folder 1/Inside in Folder 1

Approx like above format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose

```
SPFile file = ...; 
string absUrl = (string) file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl];
```

as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216832/how-to-get-the-absolute-url-of-a-file-in-sharepoint-library)

or you build it via the [site-related url property of SPFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.url.aspx)